# Each time I edit a Post/Reply nested form, a new reply is being added?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have a nested form which consists on a post and replies:

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
    @post.replies.build
  end
  .
  .
  .
  private
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:content, :user, replies_attributes: [:content])
    end
end
```

**replies_controller.rb:**

```
class RepliesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_reply, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @reply = Reply.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @reply = Reply.new(reply_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @reply.save
        format.html { redirect_to @reply, notice: 'Reply was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @reply }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @reply.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @reply.update(reply_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @reply, notice: 'Reply was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @reply.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_reply
      @reply = Reply.find(params[:id])
    end

    def reply_params
      params.require(:reply).permit(:content) 
    end
end
```

**post.rb:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :replies, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :replies, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**reply.rb:**

```
class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

**posts/_reply_fields.html.erb:**

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :content, "Reply" %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :content, :rows => 3 %><br />
</p>
```

**posts/_form.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :user %>
  </div>
  <div class="replies">
    <%= f.fields_for :replies do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'reply_fields', :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**schema.rb:**

```
  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.string   "user"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "replies", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "post_id"
  end
```

The **output** in the replies parts is just:

```
<div class="replies">
  </div>
```

Now, everything works OK if I submit the form: a new post and reply is created. But each time I edit a post a new reply is created.

So if I edit a post like this:

```
post title: Post Title 1
post content: Post Content 1
reply content: Reply Content 1
```

I end up with something like this:

```
post title: Post Title 1
post content: Post Content 1
reply content: Reply Content 1
reply content: Reply Content 1
```

and on and on and on...

I want could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your `posts/_form.html.erb` the submit path is @post which is fine for creating new record,for editing you need to have path `edit_post_path` which sends the post id for updating. You can run the command `rake routes` to check the paths for corresponding actions.